# Word applies heading style to line with break

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to create a Word document where a part of the page is two-column. When I insert a Column Break and set the first line of the new column to be a header, the Heading style also applies to the column break. What's the best way to fix this.

[image: This is what happens]

Comment: I assume you mean "Heading" style. http://addbalance.com/word/headersheadings.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best approach, but I have a working solution with a style separator:

1. Insert column break.
2. Press Ctrl+Alt+Enter.
3. Type heading text, press Enter.
4. Select heading and last paragraph mark and set a heading style to this selection.

Comment: This should work. Version of Word?

It is confusing, but the column break is still part of the paragraph that begins the new column. This used to be a problem with page breaks as well.

Comment: This method works in Word 2010.

Comment: If on a Mac, at this time there is no Style Separator, as such. You can get the same result with a hidden paragraph mark. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Style_Separator

Answer (score 1):

> This method does not work in Word 2013, as Ctrl-Alt-Enter now inserts a second column break

No. This is not true. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> still inserts style separators. You might have confused it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, which inserts column breaks (Both the Above statements are true for Office 2007-2019 — [official Ref 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2#bkmk_specialcharwin), [Unofficial Ref 2 - for office 2007](http://www.keyxl.com/aaa367b/5/microsoft-word-keyboard-shortcuts.htm))

This is true, unless you've remapped the shortcuts. Either way, there exists another way to insert the special character which will work nevertheless - By adding it to your Quick Access Toolbar:

1. Go to `File > Options > Quick Access Toolbar`
2. Select `All commands` in `Chose commands from` dropdown.
3. Search for `Style Separator` (For simple navigation just press 'T' and scroll a bit up...)
4. Click 'add' and then 'ok'

Then you can just click on the button in Quick Access Toolbar whenever you need it.